# Lost 2 GB of internal storage after unsuccessful try to swap

Tags: root-access, internal-storage, ram

I have a Alcatel C5 5036, initially with 4GB internal storage
I have rooted it successfully,
I tried to increase ram with "[ROEHSOFT RAM Expander (SWAP)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.swapit.expander.de)",
After some unsuccessful tries, 
While any SWAP was not created,
The internal storage decreased to 2.05GB,
2 GB has been lost!
I tried SWAPoff for several times, but there was no any SWAP for it to remove now in storage or any other explorer location, it shows the total capacity of internal storage as 2.05GB, instead of 4GB. Please help me as to how to recover the lost storage.

Comment: Apparently you did not follow the proper procedure. You were supposed to create the swap file on an external SD card with a special swap partition, but now the internal storage has been repartitioned, which is non-standard and the app does not recognize it properly. Only way to get your storage back is to repartition your device, which needs professional help as your device's chipset is not well documented.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change partition size using GParted

---

Using adb you can dump whole internal storage to your PC
this will work only on linux but since you will have to use gparted it shouldn't be a problem
connect phone to the PC and type in the terminal

```
adb shell
su
cat /dev/block/mmcblk0 | busybox nc -l 6666
```

aasuming that your pc and phone are in the same network and phone's IP address is `192.168.0.101`
in another terminal type:

```
nc 192.168.0.101 6666 > dump.img
```

after few minutes transfer should end and then you can edit `dump.img` using gparted:

```
gparted dump.img
```

after editing partition layout dump it back to your phone
(you may need to remount all partitions read-only before it)

```
adb shell
su
busybox nc -l 6666 > /dev/block/mmcblk0
```

and in another terminal

```
cat dump.img | nc 192.168.0.101 6666
```

Comment: Oh. Maybe you include how to do that? GParted runs on a computer. The device to be repartitioned resides on internal storage, which cannot be accessed from GParted. So how to proceed? Put the LiveCD into the Android device? // Hint: The approach might work, but the tool is wrong. Check for [Android partitioning apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_storagemedia#group_915), and there's e.g. one app from the same dev (Roehsoft) – and also an Android version of GParted (named *AParted*).

Comment: post updated with instructions

Comment: I'm glad you edited your answer and I took back my vote too. Too bad, my flag would now be declined. :) @Izzy, you might want to see the answer.

Comment: @Firelord Yupp, much better now. Though I find it too complicated: I'd use e.g. [AParted](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sylkat.AParted) directly on the device. Though taking a storage-device backup before (first step of this answer) is a good idea, just in case. Btw: The downvote is not mine.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer given by rav_kr](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/127077/16575) certainly provides a solution – but looks a bit complicated to me. Not only does it require Busybox on the device, and deals with partitions over the network (one more possible cause of problems) – it involves too many steps. Hence here's my suggestion:

1. Backup the storage device (as described in mentioned answer) is always a good idea. But we can use an easier approach:

   ```
   adb shell "su -c \"cat /dev/block/mmcblk0 > /sdcard/mmcblk0.img\""
   ```
2. Install [AParted](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sylkat.AParted) (the Android pendant to GParted) and use it to re-partition the storage device directly:

[image: AParted] [image: AParted]
<sup>*AParted* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sylkat.AParted); click images for larger variants)</sup>

Done. In case anything goes wrong, reverting changes is as easy as

```
adb shell "su -c \"cat /sdcard/mmcblk0.img > /dev/block/mmcblk0\""
```

And if you want to take a look first, there are other [Android partitioning apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_storagemedia#group_915) available as well – two from the same dev as your *RAM Expander*; but at least these two are rather expensive, while *AParted* comes for free.